# How to achieve SharePoint built-in content approval workflow using MS flow for SharePoint Online Modern Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-approval, modern-document-library, ms-flow

I have a SharePoint Online Modern Site with the default Document Library. Now Client want to implement content approval over the library and they want that to be through MS Flow. Our client needs below things in it.

-Once the document gets uploaded the Approval status should be Draft.
-User should be able to select the draft document and click on some link to submit for approval.
-The approval should go to a specific SharePoint Group
-Any of the user in the SP Group should be able to approve.
-During Approval, the document status should be Pending

I know this is fully achievable through built in approval workflow in share point. But how through MS Flow? I tried to use "Request Manager Approval for selected file template", but here I don't see option of sending approval to Specific SP Group and during approval the document status does not set to "Pending".

So, please help me on this.

Thanks in advance!